# Trying to use java to read a csv file and choose specific rows/columns

Tags: java, csv, rows

I've been trying to make a java program that reads a CSV file with random names in it.Each row has a name, their relation to another name(father, sibling etc)and the name they're related to, all seperated with "," .My program can currently read the whole file and show everything in it.What I'm trying to do is have the user be able to write 2 names and, if they're in the same row, see their relation.So far it doesn't work.In my code below you can see that I made it so if the 2 name inputs(name1 and name2)match with names inside to do that sout command to show their relation, but the sout never happens.No error either, after giving input to the 2 names the program just finishes.

```
String csvF = "C:\\file.csv";
String line = "";
String csvSplitBy = ",";
try (BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvF))) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please write the first name");
    String name1 = input.nextLine();
    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Now please write the second name");
    String name2 = input2.nextLine();
    while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] s = line.split(csvSplitBy);

        if (name1 == s[0] && name2 == s[2]) {
            System.out.println(name1 + "is" + s[2] + "to/of" + name2);
        }

    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} } }
```

Comment: Have you traced the code to verify the names actually match a name in the file? There may be a space which will cause the names to NOT match, I suggest trimming the names and also case may matter, I suggest setting the names to lower or uppercase before comparing. Also, since you are looking for a relation between the TWO names, wouldn’t you also need to check if `name1 == s[2]` and/or `name2 == s[0]` ? It may help to output that the names were not found, how else is the user going to know?

Comment: Looking closer at the code, are you sure you are checking the correct indexes? If a match is found, then the output looks odd… if `name1 = Bob` and `name2 = Sally`, and a match is found, then the output would be … “Bob is Sally to/of Sally”?  Is `s[2]` the relation or the name?

Comment: Thank you for replying guys.I made sure to write the names always with correct uppercase/lowercase and spaces.I did add an else command to see if it really finds the names and turns out it doesn't.I originally put s[0]as the first name and s[2]as the second, but as the second comment noticed, I misstyped and put s[2] as their relation instead of s[1].I changed it and still nothing.It keeps doing the else command, not finding them.I also noticed that java counts the spaces between names as _ so I made sure to add that too where it was shown but it still doesn't find them.

Answer (score 0):

After finally testing this, I am pretty sure that the line…

```
if (name1 == s[0] && name2 == s[2])
```

is failing because the == is comparing the string `name1` with the “address” of `s[0]`… not `s[0]`'s contents. Change the line to the code below and it should work.

```
if (name1.equals(s[0]) && name2.equals(s[2])) { …
```